# how to change the default welcome message in asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I have installed asterisk 1.8.9.0. and i have installed ekiga soft phone too. When tried to call using ekiga, the caller can hear the default message , "Congrats, you have successfully installed astrisk etc." . How can I change the default welcome message. where should I write the dial plan..

please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk dialplan is written in /etc/asterisk/extensions.conf

Note, however that Asterisk "dialplan" is it's own scripting language that requires some study and technical mastery to customize.

See Asterisk the Definative Guide for configuration help:
http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449332426/

or the official documentation:
https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Dialplan+Fundamentals

Instead, you may wish to install Asterisk using a GUI, which can be done easily with AsteriskNOW
http://www.asterisk.org/downloads/asterisknow

With AsteriskNOW and the FreePBX GUI you can customize your dialplan with a web admin interface. (no need to customize text files.)